# selinux allowing custom systemd service

Tags: systemd, selinux

in RHEL 8.8, I have a custom `/etc/systemd/system/custom.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=custom

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/scripts/custom.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

my `/root/scripts/custom.sh` is `root.root -rwx------`.

I see in `/var/log/messages` statements about execution denied on the script by selinux.  What do I need to do in order for my `/root/scripts/custom.sh` script to run from my `custom.service` ?

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/a/1032766/615456) is probably what you are looking for (SELinux allows to run binaries (in systemd) from certain directories, I guess the directories whose have the `bin_t` label)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the output of `sudo ausearch -ts recent -m avc` right after you've ran `sudo systemctl start custom.service`. The audit logs will show the SELinux AVC denial.